# Windows Advanced audit settings for ALL powershell terminals

Tags: powershell, cmd, registry, audit, powershell-ise

On powershell I have the command to view the advanced audit settings from a registry key only by running as administrator, by running 
`(get-acl hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run -audit).GetAuditRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])`

I was wondering if there's an alternative way of doing this on the regular powershell terminal? as when i try with the command above i get this output `get-acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give yourself the 'Manage auditing and Security log' (SeSecurityPrivilege) user privilege to do that.

- Open Group Policy editor (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type
  gpedit.msc for the local machine)
- Go to Computer Configuration ->
  Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User
  Rights Assignment
- Double-click the 'Manage auditing and Security log'
  entry and add yourself to the users having that privilege.

You'll probably have to log off and back on before the new setting becomes active.

It can also be done using Powershell. I found a module [cSecurityOptions](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/cSecurityOptions/) and also [Carbon](https://github.com/pshdo/Carbon/) has a function called `Grant-Privilege`. I haven't tried though..

Hope this helps